# Don't forget to upvote the questions!

Tags: discussion

I'm seeing quite a few questions being answered, but left at 0 votes. I think, in most cases, if a question is worth answering, It's probably worth an upvote, too. Thoughts?

Answer (score 14):

One of the benefits/side effects of a heavily up-voted question is that it gets broadcast across the network — free advertising, bringing more people into this site. I use that outcome as a catalyst/reminder to up-vote particularly good questions.

Whenever you see an intriguing question that makes you think *"Wow, that's what makes this site worthwhile"* or even just *"hey, I wish folks knew about this"*, that's what triggers me to hit that up-vote button out of reflex.

Unfortunately, that reflex only comes with top-of-mind awareness and reminders like this post. Keep up the good work and [vote, vote, vote](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).

Answer (score 7):

My personal method for choosing what to up vote is to vote on the questions that I consider will be useful to others, though I do err on the side of generosity, and I do also vote for questions which clearly demonstrate some effort in their authoring.

Answer (score 4):

I think its good to keep voting right answers.I have couple of cases on my answers where the one who posted the question marked it right but no votes and that discourages me to spend time here.

Answer (score 4):

I am still seeing this trend. If you feel the question is worth answering, it should also be upvoted. Let's try and give some points to our new users to promote the boards here!